# While finding subsets of given array through recurssion, my code is giving wrong answer

Tags: python, recursion

I have to return the subsets of the given array, I know th elogic that while reccuring we have to first include elements than backtarack and then exclude elements of the given array. But while implementing in python, I dont know what is going wrong, the return list is not containing anything

```
class Solution:

    def subsets(self, A):

        def sub(i, A, lis, ans):
            if i==len(A):
                ans.append(lis)
                return

            lis.append(A[i])
            sub(i+1, A, lis, ans)
            lis.remove(A[i])
            sub(i+1, A, lis, ans)
            
        ans = []
        lis = []
        n = len(A)
        
        sub(0, A, lis, ans)
        
        return ans
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: You might consider modifying your solution so that `sub()` returns something.